# Android: Eclipse: The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

Tags: android, eclipse

12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.gpluslogin/info.androidhive.gpluslogin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null options are not permitted for this Api
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null options are not permitted for this Api
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.o.b(Unknown Source)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.addApi(Unknown Source)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at info.androidhive.gpluslogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
12-01 13:46:33.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3724):     ... 11 more

**Eclipse is unable to render Sign In button from the package com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
I have tried cleaning the project ( restarting eclipse) as well as updating the google playservices to the latest ones !**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, repeated restarting of eclipse solved the problem and I don't know how. However, this might be the solution for you.

Open SDK Manager
2. Look for Google Play Services updates.
3. If yes, update it.
4. Now delete the google-play-services_lib **( remove contents from disk SHOULD REMAIN UNCHECKED )**
5. Restart Eclipse
6. Add Google Play Service library again.
7. Go to the Properties->Android of your project and remove and add the library again.
8. Clean all projects
9. RESTART again

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Comment: Hey @Anakooter i did the same thing restarted eclipse, build, clean and it worked.! thanks mate.!

Comment: Just a clean, then restart sorted it for me

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in the build.gradle :

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    ...
}
```

i dont know why but in latest google play lib the integration is not automatic, at least for me

Comment: The poster is using Eclipse. Unlikely gradle is being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace this code inside your Oncreate, Its Works for me

 //Google Sign in
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, new Plus.PlusOptions.Builder().build()) 
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

instead of this

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Plus.API,null)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```